# How to generate a rails link with an AR validation message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to give a link to the contact us page on failure of a validation. I've tried this to no avail:

```
validates_acceptance_of :not_an_agency, :on => :create,
:message => "must be confirmed. If you are an agency please #{link_to "Contact Us", contact_path}"
```

Anyone know how to get past this one?

Jack

Answer (score 1):

As of Rails 3.1 you can also do:

```
view_context.link_to "Contact Us", contact_path
```

Also, just to be strict, the original poster's code example is missing a close quote on "Contact Us"

Answer (score 0):

With Rails 3

you need include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper in your Model and define the message like a lambda to be interpret when needed

```
class XXX < AR
  extend ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

  validates_acceptance_of :not_an_agency, :on => :create,
                          :message => lambda {"must be confirmed. If you are an agency please #{link_to "Contact Us", contact_path}"}

end
```

With Rails 2

it's the same but you need define the :host each time.

```
class XXX < AR
  extend ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

  validates_acceptance_of :not_an_agency, :on => :create,
                          :message => lambda {"must be confirmed. If you are an agency please #{link_to "Contact Us", contact_path(:host => 'http://example.org')}"}

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried your Rails 3 solution but am still getting the same error - undefined local variable or method `contact_path' for #<Class:0x35f95e4>

Comment: BTW there is a small typo- you didn't close the string after "Contact Us"

Comment: I update my answer with typo fix. So it's more extend than include :)

Answer (score 0):

Shingara's answer helps you with the "link_to" part, but it still crashes on the "contact_path" part.   My solution:

```
validates_acceptance_of :not_an_agency, :on => :create,
                      :message => lambda {|e,f| "must be confirmed. If you are an agency please <a href=\"#{Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.contact_path}\">Contact Us</a>".html_safe}
```

I choose to just type `<a href.../>` rather than doing an `include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper`.   That's up to you.

Also note the `.html_safe`.   It's actually useless because Rails loses it when it adds the field name and you'll have to make it safe on the view side again.   But I put it in anyways in the hope that Rails will eventually fix that piece of brokenness.

And I have no idea what the |e,f| are for.   I had to put them in to fix up a silly argument number mismatch error.