# Put link into validation message in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a way to put a link in a form error message in rails?

For example in my model, I have:

```
class Shoe < ApplicationRecord
    
  validates :name, uniqueness: true      
            
end
```

So when validation occurs, the name shows the default message: `"Name is already taken"`.

But it is possible to put a link to the shoe with the name already taken?
Like this:

`Name is already taken. Go _here_ to see the shoe.`

Comment: check this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880876/how-to-generate-a-rails-link-with-an-ar-validation-message`

Answer (score 1):

[Rails Validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message) allows you to have a custom error message. Your validation could be something like this assuming each shoe record has a url.

```
validates :name, uniqueness: {
  message: ->(object, data) do
    "#{data[:value]} is taken already! See this shoe here #{Shoe.find_by({name: data[:value]}).url}"
  end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using template to display your error, you can do something like:

```
<% if @shoe.errors.any? && @shoe.errors.include? :name %>
  <p>
    This name is already taken <%= link_to "Go here to see the shoe", shoe_path(Shoe.find_by(name: params[:shoe][:name]) %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why show "This name is already taken..." if the error is for presence of name or say, wrong format of name?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh the OP asked with a uniqueness validation example, i just showed one example of what could be done in that case meaning you can do the same for every errors you want to custom

Answer (score 0):

I made something similar with sovalina answer.

```
<% if shoe.errors.any? %> 
    <div id="error_explanation">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            The form contains <%= pluralize(show.errors.count, "error") %>.
        </div>
        <ul>
            <% shoe.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li> 
            <% end %>
            <%if shoe.errors[:name][0] == "has already been taken" %>
                <% @shoe = Shoe.where(name: shoe.name).first %>
                <%= link_to "Go to the shoe", @shoe %>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>  
    <% end %>
```

and its works, when the name its already taken its show me a link to the shoe.